# MongoImport: How to import json file (which contains guid) via powershell

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I know how to import json files via powershell, but is it possible to import a json file via powershell, which contains Guids as IDs?

C# converts the Guid into mongodb type LUUID.

For Example I want to make integration tests with Mongo2go - and I want to import json files as sample data. How should the json file look like, so that the mongoimporter understands that the field ID is from LUUID?

I have tried following Jsons:

Option1

```
    {
       "_id": LUUID("8a95184b-5125-4b0d-914e-8e4650f19b5c"),
       "Date" : {$date: "2014-03-20T03:09:27.000+01:00"},
       "Name" : Foo
    }
```

Option2

```
    {
       "_id": $LUUID("8a95184b-5125-4b0d-914e-8e4650f19b5c"),
       "Date" : {$date: "2014-03-20T03:09:27.000+01:00"},
       "Name" : Foo
    }
```

Option3

```
    {
       "_id": {LUUID : "8a95184b-5125-4b0d-914e-8e4650f19b5c"},
       "Date" : {$date: "2014-03-20T03:09:27.000+01:00"},
       "Name" : Foo
    }
```

Option 4

```
    {
       "_id": {$LUUID : "8a95184b-5125-4b0d-914e-8e4650f19b5c"},
       "Date" : {$date: "2014-03-20T03:09:27.000+01:00"},
       "Name" : Foo
    }
```

Option 5

```
    {
       "_id": {LUUID : {"8a95184b-5125-4b0d-914e-8e4650f19b5c"}},
       "Date" : {$date: "2014-03-20T03:09:27.000+01:00"},
       "Name" : Foo
    }
```

Option 6

```
    {
       "_id": {$LUUID : {"8a95184b-5125-4b0d-914e-8e4650f19b5c"}},
       "Date" : {$date: "2014-03-20T03:09:27.000+01:00"},
       "Name" : Foo
    }
```

But none of them worked.

Comment: Whats a C# guid, compared to a "normal" guid?

Comment: @RandRadom what I wanted to say is that it is a guid, created with c#

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this?  Im facin the same issue with a mock api I have.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find the answer is to export the data with `mongoexport` and check the output format. And the format turned out to be not very simple for the guessing:

> "_id":{"$binary":"GNIkQiYyu0CNNRsRHBQqLA==", "$type":"03"}

This data was retrieved for following GUID: `{4224d218-3226-40bb-8d35-1b111c142a2c}`. That Base64 string is decoded to bytes array that is returned by `Guid.ToByteArray()` method

> 18 d2 24 42 26 32 bb 40 8d 35 1b 11 1c 14 2a 2c

Now when you know the format you could easily build required json. However it seems much easier just to fill the collection with that data and export it with mongoexport.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little piece of code that could help you.

- The Parse method takes a filename as input and returns a new temp filename with the transormed content
- The ParseNUUIDs takes a json string and transforms NUUID('...') to their MongoDB object representations

Hope it can help someone...

```
function ParseNUUIDs($content){
    $matches = ([regex]'(NUUID\(\")(.*)(\"\))').Matches($content);
    Foreach($m in $matches){
        $guid = [GUID]$m.Groups[2].Value
        $bytes = $guid.ToByteArray()
        $b64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
        $r = "{""" +  "$" + "binary"": """ + $b64 + """, """ + "$" +  "type"": ""03""}"
        $content = $content.replace($m.Value, $r)
    }
    return $content
}

function Parse($filename){
    $content = Get-Content $filename -Raw
    $content = ParseNUUIDs $content
    $tempFile = New-TemporaryFile
    $content | Out-File -FilePath $tempFile -Encoding utf8
    return $tempFile
}
```